# When Mongoose QueryStream emits an error event what is the state of the stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am opening up a stream to my DB through [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) and would like to know what is the state of the stream when it emits an error event? Does that mean an individual document that is being streamed had an error and the stream will continue to pipe data? Or does it mean the entire stream had an error and the stream is now corrupt/closed?

Here is the sample code from Mongoose' docs:

```
var stream = Model.find().stream();

stream.on('data', function (doc) {
  // do something with the mongoose document
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // What state is the stream here?????
}).on('close', function () {
  // the stream is closed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For [Streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) in general, an `'error'` event usually means the stream has halted and won't be emitting anymore `'data'`.

Emitting an `'error'` is generally equivalent to a [`throw` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw), which breaks application flow. And, similar to a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), an `.on('error')` callback is a way of handling the error.

With [Domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html), the `'error'` may even have been triggered by a `throw`.